# My android game build is freezing every 2 seconds on my mobile phone

Tags: unity-game-engine, logcat

My android game in some mobile phone (mate 10) freezing every 2 seconds. I debug it from LogCat. Can anyone has an idea?

LogCat:

```
2023.05.24 20:55:19.118 13190 13579 Debug   PlayerBase::stop() from IPlayer
2023.05.24 20:55:19.119 13190 13579 Debug AudioTrack stop(513): called with 100804 frames delivered
2023.05.24 20:55:19.153 13190 13190 Debug DecorView showOrHideHighlightView: hasFocus=false; winMode=1; isMrgNull=true
2023.05.24 20:55:19.153 13190 13190 Warn HwRemoteInputMethodManager isCasting false because IHwDistributedWindowManager is invalid.
0001.01.01 00:00:00.000 -1 -1 Info  --------- beginning of system
2023.05.24 20:55:19.178 13190 13190 Debug ActivityThread Won't deliver top position change in state=4
2023.05.24 20:55:19.204 13190 13190 Verbose AudioManager getStreamVolume streamType: 3 volume: 15
2023.05.24 20:55:19.210 13190 13190 Debug DecorView showOrHideHighlightView: hasFocus=true; winMode=1; isMrgNull=true
2023.05.24 20:55:19.212 13190 13190 Warn HwRemoteInputMethodManager isCasting false because IHwDistributedWindowManager is invalid.
2023.05.24 20:55:19.233 13190 13579 Verbose AudioManager getStreamVolume streamType: 3 volume: 15
2023.05.24 20:55:19.241 13190 13190 Verbose MediaRouter Selecting route: RouteInfo{ name=Telefon, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=Sistem types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
2023.05.24 20:55:21.252 13190 13579 Debug   PlayerBase::stop() from IPlayer
2023.05.24 20:55:21.253 13190 13579 Debug AudioTrack stop(513): called with 98880 frames delivered
2023.05.24 20:55:21.290 13190 13190 Debug DecorView showOrHideHighlightView: hasFocus=false; winMode=1; isMrgNull=true
2023.05.24 20:55:21.290 13190 13190 Warn HwRemoteInputMethodManager isCasting false because IHwDistributedWindowManager is invalid.
2023.05.24 20:55:21.329 13190 13190 Debug ActivityThread Won't deliver top position change in state=4
2023.05.24 20:55:21.356 13190 13190 Verbose AudioManager getStreamVolume streamType: 3 volume: 15
2023.05.24 20:55:21.359 13190 13190 Debug DecorView showOrHideHighlightView: hasFocus=true; winMode=1; isMrgNull=true
2023.05.24 20:55:21.360 13190 13190 Warn HwRemoteInputMethodManager isCasting false because IHwDistributedWindowManager is invalid.
2023.05.24 20:55:21.375 13190 13579 Verbose AudioManager getStreamVolume streamType: 3 volume: 15
2023.05.24 20:55:21.386 13190 13190 Verbose MediaRouter Selecting route: RouteInfo{ name=Telefon, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=Sistem types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6jsr.png)

I couldn't understand where is the problem.